# Are Trurl and Klaupacius really robots?

Tags: stanislaw-lem

"Everybody" knows that the Stanislav Lem characters Trurl and Klaupacius in *Cyberiad* are robots. But I have not found explicitly mention of this fact (in English translation at least).

Is there definite evidence of the robotic nature of the constructors?

Comment: I've never seen it it said anywhere, but the tales in The Cyberiad obviously are meant to be fairy tales that robot mommies and daddies tell to their mecha children.

Comment: @jameslarge I disagree. Much of *Bajki Robotów*, which is sometimes published together with the Cyberiad, are such robot fairy tales, but the Cyberiad proper (which is the part about Trurl) seems to be stories you're likely to tell only to adults.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### They're both robots.

This passage appears in the story '*Trurls's Machine*'

> *The room was dark, but even so, Klapaucius could see that Trurl's
>   person bore the marks of a good shellacking — though it was apparent
>   that **Trurl had gone to some trouble to touch up the scratches and
>   hammer out the dents.***

And the following passage appears in '*Altruizine OR A True Account of How Bonhomius the Hermetic Hermit Tried to Bring About Universal Happiness, and What Came of It*'

> *Klapaucius was somewhat put off by the fact that Altruizine was only for humans, which meant that robots would have to continue to endure
>   the misfortunes allotted to them in this world. I, however, made bold
>   to remind him of the solidarity of all thinking beings and the
>   necessity of aiding **our organic brothers.***